# php session in android

Tags: java, php, android, session

im writing server side for android app,
the server is WAMP baseed(php).
im using session mechanism to validate users .
when im using "postman"(chrome plugin that simulate post requets) to simulate login and some other operations the session id remain the same(not sure if it constant or invalidate after a while) as long as i stay in the same pc,
when i using other pc the session changed .
when i took the java /android code the session id chaned every time i logged in or update user detail. the php code is pretty basic i think .

my question is this: why does the session id keep changing in android and in regular browsers it's not? does the android developer should use special class or somthing? 
thank you all in advance

Amir

Comment: you need to post example code, and yes the session id should change every-time the session is started

Comment: so how come in pc each time i command "session start " the session remain the same and in android it not?
is there any "special " class in android that will simulate the same behavior as in regular browser ?
as i read in php site the session should generate new session only if the timer expierd or if the device hasn't got old session

Comment: can u answer my q man?

Comment: you need to post your code, and show examples of what you are experiencing.